# problems on Analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with this 
Let S be the disk $|z|<3$ in the complex plane and let $f:S \rightarrow C$ be an analytic function such that $f(1+\frac{\sqrt 2}{n}i)=-\frac{2}{n^2}$ for each natural number n. then what is the value of $f(\sqrt2)$

Comment: Have $f$ any other property? the point $1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}i$ merely specify a vertical line pass from $x=1$ and no other points!

Comment: Put $g(z)=(1-z)^2$ and show that $f(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}i}{n})=g(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}i}{n})$ for all natural $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f\left(1+\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)=-\frac{2}{n^2}, \quad n\in\mathbb N,
$$
means that
$$
f(z_n)=(z_n-1)^2, 
$$
whenever $z_n=\dfrac{i\sqrt{2}}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb N$.

This means that the holomorphic functions $f$ and $g(z)=(z-1)^2$ take the same value in a set with a limit point, in their domain (i.e., $z_n\to\in S$).

Therefore, $f\equiv g$.